# Why can I printf to the screen but not a file in Java?

Tags: java

I wrote a method to printf a String to an external file, but I get a compiler error on the printf method. I used another method to printf the same String to the screen, and the only difference is the file declaration and replacing System.out.printf with outFile.printf; that method has no errors. What is the error in this method, and how can I fix it?

```
public static void printFile(String master)
{
    File outFile = new File("output-file.txt");
    /* code that divides the string into tokens and assigns them to 
    variables name, diameter, mass, and gravity */
    outFile.printf("%n%-10s%10s%10s%10s", name, diameter, mass, gravity);
}
```

Comment: You said you get a compiler error. What does the error exactly say?

Comment: `printf` is not a function for `File`.

Answer (score 2):

`File` doesn't have a `printf` method - you can however create [a `PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) from a file:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(outFile);
ps.printf("%n%-10s%10s%10s%10s", name, diameter, mass, gravity);
```

Note that you will need to close the `PrintStream` when you are done using it and it is good practice to specify an encoding.

Comment: the PrintStream should be closed.. use `try(PrintStream ps = ...) { ps.printf(...) }`